# PayPal REST API Update Billing Agreement

Tags: php, json, rest, paypal

How would I go about updating a currently active billing agreement to change the bill date and charge again if the new date is in the future?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is asking about **possibilities** and **is not a concrete coding question**. If you want to know if something is possible you should **research it** and **attempt to implement it**. If you have issues while doing this you then can ask a **specific** question, **showing the code you have written**, your expected results, and your actual results. [Question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: According to their documentation it should be possible, but there are no examples given, so I am asking how can it be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-approval is fine if it works like that. I saw that there was a reactive link in the returned object after the update, but its method was POST. How do I actually redirect the user to reactivate the agreement?

Answer (score 5):

Through the update billing agreement API you can not change the plan or payment defination. For this case, you should cancel the existing billing agreement and create new agreement with new amount to meet your business requirement. This are the idea how you can achieve this:

1. Kindly cancel the existing billing agreement (recurring payment).
   (Ref: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements#agreement_cancel)
2. Use Billing Plan API to create and activate a billing plan. This is compulsory if you're going to create billing agreement.
   a. Create a Plan (kindly define new amount for the recurring payment). Ref: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans#plan_create
   b. Activate the plan that you've created. Ref:  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans#plan_update
3. Create new agreement by providing plan ID that you retrieve from steps 2. Ref: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements/#agreement_create
4. Redirect your buyer to approval_url that you receive from steps 3 to get an approval for the billing agreement and then execute the billing agreement. This is compulsory for PayPal payment.
5. After the buyer approves a PayPal payment, execute the billing agreement. You will then receive the agreement ID that you've created during this step. (Ref: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements/#agreement_execute)

I have implemented this using PHP code.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: +1 Mohd bhai, for this information, do we also have any kind of using repository available to implement this ?
thanks in anticipation

Comment: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK.
This papypal-php-SDK having examples with different methods.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, the best way to go about it would be to create a new billing agreement, and get the user approval for the new agreement with the new bill date since the plan is already active. If the agreement was not already active, you could have changed the start date without needing reapproval from the buyer by calling [update agreement](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#update-an-agreement) with op set to replace and setting the value of start date.